# Springboot HikariCP

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I using springboot with HikariCP, but after a while my app crash and I got the error:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
...

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-6 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
```

This is my aplication.properties

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_dnaso
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.16.1.10:5432/db_dnaso
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=dna44100
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

So I have a lot of save, find and anothers access to DB, how can I visualize how method are blocking my connection?

tks

Answer (score 8):

It looks like your your database server is running out of connection. Default value for property `maximumPoolSize` in Hikari is 10. That means it will try to create 10 connection on server startup and it will not start if not able to acquire 10 connection or may fail if your db server pool size having less connection in the pool as you are creating using Hikari configuration.
If you are able to start Spring Boot server and then facing this issue then try enabling `leakDetectionThreshold` and check which connection is taking more time and not returning to Hikari pool .

```
spring:
  datasource:        
    hikari:                    
      leak-detection-threshold: 2000
```

Answer (score 3):

In springboot, you can set `spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=10000` (in milliseconds) in `application.properties`.

And the default  value for `maximumPoolSize` is `10`. You can change it with `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=xx`.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the `leakDetectionThreshold`, set to something like 1 minute (60000ms).  It is likely that you have a connection leak somewhere ... a connection is borrowed but never closed (returned).

Comment: how can I enable this in springboot?? tks

Comment: @brettw does it terminate the leaked connection also, or just report it

Comment: @shivam It does not terminate the leaked connection, that could be bad. It could be that the detection reports the leak just seconds before the transaction actually *does* complete successfully, and the connection is "un-leaked". The expectation is that developers will find and fix any reported leaks quickly. HikariCP will not "patch over" coding errors such as this, it is too easy for developers to ignore them.